# Easiest way to create a wedge-like form

Tags: three.js

I am quite a beginner in Three.js and I was wondering if there is an easy solution for the following wedge-like geometric shape.

[wedge-like geometric shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUJn8.jpg)

I've been using the [PolyhedronGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/PolyhedronGeometry) but I think I'm overthinking the problem. Is there an easier way, maybe with a simple BoxGeometry?

Thanks

Comment: Such a simple shape might be easiest to build yourself by calculating the vertices. Or, you could check out ExtrudeGeometry: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry

Comment: Berthur is right. Learning how to use [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) (and its instanced and interleaved counterparts) will open up a HUGE world of custom shapes, not to mention complete control over how they're created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deform a box geometry at your will:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-5, 5, 10).setLength(5);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2));

let g = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 2, 1);
let pos = g.attributes.position;
for(let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
  if (pos.getX(i) < 0 && pos.getY(i) > 0) pos.setY(i, 0); // change Y-coord by condition
}
g.computeVertexNormals(); // don't forget to re-compute normals

let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "aqua"});
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
</script>
```